# Only allow one UIGestureRecognizer available at a time Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a list of `UIView`. Each of them has its own `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. How can I make an only `UIView` available to be dragged at a time?
Now if I use 2 fingers, I can drag 2 `UIView`.

Comment: please add code to show how you are doing it

Comment: You should probably use one touch gesture for the container and then detect based on tap location which view was touched in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution
Use isExclusiveTouch on UIView will make only one UIGestureRecognizer available at a time

Comment: you just set `isExclusiveTouch ` to `true` when init your `UIView`. Automatically only the `UIGestureRecognizer ` of that `UIView` is available at a time.